# Rails 4- iterating over RDF::Query::Solutions & RDF::Query::Solution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sparql, rdf

I have a small Rails app that processes some sparql query results. 
The sparql creates a solutions set `@solutions_array` of 6859 solutions. The solutions set is of class RDF::Query::Solutions, within it are the 6859 instances of class RDF::Query::Solution. Each RDF::Query::Solution contains two variables, :unit and :battle. According to the documentation these should be available as solution.unit & solution.battle. When i use `@solutions_array.first.unit` i get exactly the result expected. Every thing above the dashes in my output works as expected.

> Discovered Concepts
>
> Class: class RDF::Query::Solutions
>
> Count: class 6859
>
> First Query Solution:
>
> #
>
> URI:...resource/3rd_Guards_Infantry_Division_(German_Empire)>,
>   :battle=>#})>
>
> First Unit:
>   ...resource/3rd_Guards_Infantry_Division_(German_Empire)
>
> ---
>
> Class: RDF::Query::Solution
>
> Inspect:
>
> #
>
> URI:...resource/3rd_Guards_Infantry_Division_(German_Empire)>,
>   :battle=>#})>
>
> Class: RDF::Query::Solution
>
> Inspect:
>
> #
>
> URI:...resource/3rd_Guards_Infantry_Division_(German_Empire)>,
>   :battle=>#})>

The output is produced by these few lines:

```
<div class="span3 offset1">
      <h2> Discovered Concepts </h2>
            <P>Class:  class <%= @solutions_array.class %> </p> 
            <P>Count:  class <%= @solutions_array.count %> </p> 
            <p>First Query Solution: <%= @solutions_array.first.inspect %></p>
            <p>First Unit: <%= @solutions_array.first.unit %></p>
            <p>-------------------------------------------------</p>        
            <%= @solutions_array.each do |solution| %>
              <p>Class: <%= solution.class %></p>
              <p>Inspect: <%= solution.inspect %></p>

            <% end %>
```

Now, when i try to access my variables when iterating over the solutions, {|solution| puts solution.battle } throws the error 'method unknown'. When i try the same using irb i get no error. My code looks as follows (same as above, except for the single added line `<p>Unit: <%= solution.unit %></p>`:

```
<div class="span3 offset1">
      <h2> Discovered Concepts </h2>
            <P>Class:  class <%= @solutions_array.class %> </p> 
            <P>Count:  class <%= @solutions_array.count %> </p> 
            <p>First Query Solution: <%= @solutions_array.first.inspect %></p>
            <p>First Unit: <%= @solutions_array.first.unit %></p>
            <p>-------------------------------------------------</p>        
            <%= @solutions_array.each do |solution| %>
              <p>Class: <%= solution.class %></p>
              <p>Inspect: <%= solution.inspect %></p>
              <p>Unit: <%= solution.unit %></p>
            <% end %>
```

Running this code results in:

```
   > NoMethodError in Pages#extract

    > Showing/.../app/views/pages/extract.html.erb where line #20 raised:
    > undefined method `unit' for #<RDF::Query::Solutions:0x007fd17b17bca0>
    > Extracted source (around line #20): 
20   <p>Unit: <%= solution.unit %>
```

What's funny is that the error says that "unit" is no method for the class RDF::Query::Solutions...which is in principle true, but the solution.inspect shows that i'm working on an instance of the class RDF::Query::Solution, for which the variable name should be available...

What am i doing wrong ?or is this a bug in RDF.rb ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the query code?

One possible cause is `optional` clauses in the SPARQL query, which would result in some variables being unbound in the results. In this case some of your `RDF::Query::Solutions` will have variable bindings for `:unit` and others will not.

For example, I did:

```
results = client.select(:s, :p, :o, :contains).where([:s, :p, :o])
  .optional([:s, RDF::URI('http://www.w3.org/ns/ldp#contains'), :contains])
  .execute

results.count  #=> 866

contains = results.to_a.select { |solutions| solution.bound?(:contains) }
contains.count #=> 575
```

Where 575 of the 866 triples in my SPARQL endpoint match the predicate in the optional pattern.

The other ~300 will give the behavior you see. If this is what is going on for you, you can make your `#unit` call conditional on `#bound?(:unit)`, or otherwise filter the unbound items.

I added a [patch](https://github.com/ruby-rdf/rdf/pull/286) which makes this slightly nicer with `#respond_to?`. I'll push to backport for the 1.x release series.

If this isn't helpful, posting a limited set of sample data and a query that will reproduce the problem will help us track down the problem.